# Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces , $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function , $A$ be a bounded subset of $X$ and let $B =f(A)$.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces , $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function , $A$ be a bounded subset of $X$ and let $B =f(A)$. Then $B$ is :

$(i) $  bounded

$(ii) $ bounded if $A$ is also closed

$(iii) $ bounded if $A$ is compact

$(iv) $ bounded if $A$ is complete.

**Attempt:**

Since $A$ is a bounded subset of $X \implies d_X(a_1,a_2) <\delta~~\forall~a_1,a_2 \in A$.

Now, since $f$ is continuous, by definition, $d_Y(f(a_1), f(a_2))< \epsilon~~$ whenever $d_X(a_1,a_2) <\delta $.

Which means $f$ must be bounded as well. So, option $(i)$ should be correct.

Could someone please confirm if I am right?

Thank you for your help in this regard.

Comment: $f:(0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two $\delta$s you use are different. In particular, the $\delta $ in the definition of continuity depends on $\epsilon $, and there's no guarantee that there exists $\epsilon $ such that $\delta $ is as big as the $\delta $ in the definition of boundedness.

For a counterexample, consider $f: (0, 1) \to \mathbb R$ given by $x \mapsto \frac1x$.